# An example for Viewshed analysis in Python

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, grass-gis, viewshed

My goal: Using a .TIF DEM, I would like to conduct a viewshed analysis. This is to be used as one feature for a larger program written in Python that will significantly improve work quality in my profession. Ultimately, I am looking for a binary output raster that I can manipulate with GeoPandas or Shapely, then plot as polygons in Folium.

[Raster data viewshed analysis with Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409013) was extremely helpful, but I have been unable to implement the suggested methods successfully. Below is my closest successful attempt using GDAL, but I have not found a specific example of the required inputs in the documentation.

```
from osgeo import gdal

band = gdal.Open('elevation.TIF').GetRasterBand(1)

gdal.ViewshedGenerate(
    srcBand = band,
    driverName = 'GTiff',
    targetRasterName = 'viewtest.TIF',
    creationOptions = 'COMPRESS=NONE',
    observerX = test_center[1],
    observerY = test_center[0],
    observerHeight = 1.9,
    targetHeight = 2,
    visibleVal = 1,
    invisibleVal = 0,
    outOfRangeVal = 0,
    noDataVal = 0,
    dfCurvCoeff = 1 - 1/7,
    mode = 'NORMAL',
    maxDistance = 1000)
```

I get the following error, related to the fourth line: creationOptions

```
File ~\anaconda3\envs\ARES\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py:4084, in ViewshedGenerate(*args, **kwargs)
   4082 def ViewshedGenerate(*args, **kwargs):
   4083     r"""ViewshedGenerate(Band srcBand, char const * driverName, char const * targetRasterName, char ** creationOptions, double observerX, double observerY, double observerHeight, double targetHeight, double visibleVal, double invisibleVal, double outOfRangeVal, double noDataVal, double dfCurvCoeff, GDALViewshedMode mode, double maxDistance, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void * callback_data=None, GDALViewshedOutputType heightMode=GVOT_NORMAL, char ** papszOptions=None) -> Dataset"""
-> 4084     return _gdal.ViewshedGenerate(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: in method 'ViewshedGenerate', argument 4 of type 'char **'
```

Here is the [documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#raster-gtiff) I found related to creationOptions for drivers, but I was not able to discern how to implement it specifically in Python. I cannot find anywhere to describe what format needs to be passed into the function.

I am not invested in any specific method/GIS- I have also tried QGIS and GRASS APIs to no avail, and [this package](https://github.com/jonnyhuck/Viewshed) but I was unable to install it successfully.

Answer (score 3):

When I set `creationOptions=None` I was able to avoid that particular error. However, I suspect you will have a problem with `mode='NORMAL` as that is what I'm currently stuck on.

EDIT: From the gdal_alg.h file contained somewhere in the package, I discovered that the GDALViewshedMode is an enumerated type with the following enumerations:

```
GVM_Diagonal = 1,
GVM_Edge = 2,
GVM_Max = 3,
GVM_Min = 4
```

So if you do fix the `creationOptions` issue, replace `mode=Normal` with a number 1 to 4 to get that option to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The Python API documentation for the ViewshedGenerate algorithm is at https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.ViewshedGenerate

> osgeo.gdal.ViewshedGenerate(Band srcBand, char const * driverName,
> char const * targetRasterName, char ** creationOptions, double
> observerX, double observerY, double observerHeight, double
> targetHeight, double visibleVal, double invisibleVal, double
> outOfRangeVal, double noDataVal, double dfCurvCoeff, GDALViewshedMode
> mode, double maxDistance, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void *
> callback_data=None, GDALViewshedOutputType heightMode=GVOT_NORMAL,
> char ** options=None)→ Dataset

A complete Python example can be found from the GDAL autotest suite https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdal_viewshed.py#L161

Here as slightly modified so it can be run with copy-paste after the input parameters are edited to match the real data.

```
from osgeo import gdal

ox=[292294]
oy=[6571861]
oz=[2]
src_ds = gdal.Open('dem.tif')
ds = gdal.ViewshedGenerate(
    src_ds.GetRasterBand(1),
    "GTiff",
    "outtest.tif",
    ["INTERLEAVE=BAND"],
    ox[0],
    oy[0],
    oz[0],
    0,  # targetHeight
    255,  # visibleVal
    0,  # invisibleVal
    0,  # outOfRangeVal
    -1.0,  # noDataVal,
    0.85714,  # dfCurvCoeff
    gdal.GVM_Edge,
    0,  # maxDistance
    heightMode=gdal.GVOT_MIN_TARGET_HEIGHT_FROM_GROUND,
    options=["UNUSED=YES"],
)
```

Comment: what are the units of ox=[292294] and oy=[6571861].
If my raster is in geographic CS, must I reproject my raster and my location ox and oy before performing viewshed or can I pass them directly as lon and lat and let raster as it is?

Comment: From the documentation https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_viewshed.html: "The algorithm as implemented currently will only output meaningful results if the georeferencing is in a projected coordinate reference system." Reproject your DEM into some suitable projected system and give ox and oy in the units of that system